# Any possible way to set LINK ALIAS for regular Link Tracking (i.e., not Web Analytics Connector)

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, url

I've done my digging here, but can't get a solution.  I'd like to set a LINK ALIAS via AMPscript, but I always see my AMPscript in Link Tracking (image attached).

I tried `CONCAT` with no luck.
I tried `TreatAsContent` with no luck

All of the information here speaks to the Web Analytics Connector, but that's not what I'm after.  I just need the **LINK NAME** to appear in regular Email Tracking under **Link View** in Regular reports.

I've attached an image, but I know you smart people know what I'm talking about.

Any hacks to suggest?

[image]